# Как вывести результат groupby для сортировки DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Сохраняю результаты запроса из БД в DataFrame:

```
spent = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM spent", con)
payments = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM payments", con)
```

Теперь хочу отсортировать по столбцу с датами:

```
actual = payments.groupby(payments['ts'])
```

Вывод:

> <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000020C754CAA90>.

Хочу вывести таблицу, а не это. Тот же вывод при печати этой переменной.

Что не так?

Comment: судя по документации pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) ошибки нет: возвращается объект groupby (Returns a groupby object that contains information about the groups)

Comment: попробуйте payments.groupby(payments['ts']).mean()

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Метод `df.groupby(...)` возвращает объект типа `DataFrameGroupBy`, к которому нужно применять [`GroupBy` функции/методы](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html).

Сам по себе этот метод ничего не меняет (только подготавливает данные для группировки), поэтому нет смысла выводить его результат на печать, не применив ни одной функции к результату группировки.

PS из вопроса не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать - группировку или сортировку. Сортировка в Pandas делается так:

```
res = df.sort_values([<list of columns>])
```

но в случае чтения данных из БД имеет смысл сделать это на стороне БД:

```
payments = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM payments ORDER BY ...", con)
```